# Iterate in react using the same array

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

In a really simple app I'm trying to get 3 unique reviews. I've got an array with all reviews (`this.state.ervaringen`) (around 10 for now to test) in it with an id, name, and the review it self.

I want to get 3 unique reviews (not 2 the same) and I refresh them every 5 seconds or so)

So, I have a function which checks which ID's are showing right now. And if the randomizer hits one of those 3, it randomizes again until it got a free ID. This randomizer uses the array identifier to check this. (if the array contains 1, 3 and 4, and the result of randomizing is 3. It has to run again, therefor is the while loop)

Where is goes wrong is that react is asynchronous (I get sometimes the same review in the show array when initializing). I've found that out for now... but i don't know how to solve it.

I pass the current array of 0-2(it is empty at first start, i use a on componentdidmount to initialize the first run to get 3 random reviews)

I skip the check if the passed array is empty, otherwise it crashes. But due to the asynchronic it never checks true when initialising.

```
  SetPassReview = (ShowedReviews) => {
    // check if showed reviews already contain this ID, if it has, randomize again
    let AvailableReviews = this.state.Ervaringen // load all available reviews
    let ReviewToPass
      if (!ShowedReviews){

        while (!ShowedReviews.id.some(AvailableReviews[ReviewToPass].id)){
          //console.log('reviewids in print: '+ ShowedReviews[0].id + ShowedReviews[1].id + ShowedReviews[2].id + 'ID generated' + AvailableReviews[ReviewToPass].id)
          ReviewToPass = Math.floor(Math.random() * (AvailableReviews.length))
        }
      } else {
     
          ReviewToPass = Math.floor(Math.random() * (AvailableReviews.length))
      }

      return(AvailableReviews[ReviewToPass])
  }
```

I call this function 3 times to load the first run:

```
  SetInitialReviews = () => {
      let InitShowedReviews = [];
      console.log(InitShowedReviews)
      for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        let ObjectToAdd = this.SetPassReview(InitShowedReviews);
        
        InitShowedReviews.push(ObjectToAdd)

      }
}
```

If the 3 reviews are filled, I want to change them with the same function, but then I'll replace one in the showed array. (that function worked well)

The problem is something with asynchronous push function. But I don't know how to tackle this in a right way. I'm very used to synchronous programming till I started with react. But maybe someone can help me in the right direction?

Maybe an add, I am only debugging right now with the console.log and the first time it fires, it got instantly 3 array in it. So the loop is working. But i expect to get 3 logs, with each time an extra array in it.

Complete code here:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup} from 'react-transition-group'

class MainImgErv extends Component {
  state = {
    Ervaringen: [
      {Id: 1, Naam: 'TestPerson1', Ervaring: 'Review1'},
      {Id: 2, Naam: 'TestPerson2', Ervaring: 'Review2'},
      {Id: 3, Naam: 'TestPerson3', Ervaring: 'Review3'},
      {Id: 4, Naam: 'TestPerson4', Ervaring: 'Review4'},
      {Id: 5, Naam: 'TestPerson5', Ervaring: 'Review5'},
      {Id: 6, Naam: 'TestPerson6', Ervaring: 'Review6'},
      {Id: 7, Naam: 'TestPerson7', Ervaring: 'Review6'},
      {Id: 8, Naam: 'TestPerson8', Ervaring: 'Review7'},
      {Id: 9, Naam: 'TestPerson9', Ervaring: 'Review8'},
    ],
    ShowReviews: [],
    ReviewToPass: 0
  }
  SetPassReview = (ShowedReviews) => {
    // check if showed reviews already contain this ID, or  randomize again
    let AvailableReviews = this.state.Ervaringen
    let ReviewToPass
      if (!ShowedReviews){
        console.log('Something in the array')
        while (!ShowedReviews.id.some(AvailableReviews[ReviewToPass].id)){
          console.log('Rolling the dice again')
          ReviewToPass = Math.floor(Math.random() * (AvailableReviews.length))
        }
      } else {
          console.log('Nothing in the array')
          ReviewToPass = Math.floor(Math.random() * (AvailableReviews.length))
      }

      return(AvailableReviews[ReviewToPass])
      
  }  
  SetInitialReviews = () => {
          let InitShowedReviews = [];
          for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
            let ObjectToAdd = this.SetPassReview(InitShowedReviews);
            InitShowedReviews.push(ObjectToAdd)
            
            console.log(this.state.ShowReviews)        
          }

      this.setState({
              ShowReviews: InitShowedReviews
            })    

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.SetInitialReviews()
  }

  render() {
  const ShowReviewList = this.state.ShowReviews.map(review => {
    return(
              <TransitionGroup className="ervaring-main">
              <CSSTransition
                fadeappear={true}
                key={review.Id}
                timeout={500}
                classNames="fade">
                <p className="ervaring_text">{review.Ervaring}
                <br/>
                <span className="ervaring_naam">{'~ ' + review.Naam}</span>
                </p>
                </CSSTransition>
              </TransitionGroup>
    )
  })
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div className="main-img">
        </div>
        <div className="main-ervaringen">
        {ShowReviewList}
          </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
}
export default MainImgErv
```

When I run this code it gets constantly in the else where I log that the array is empty... which is weird. Because it is filled with 3 items.

Comment: Hey Ferrox, you haven't shared any of the React code. Pushing to an array isn't asynchronous. So my guess is the problem is elsewhere, but I'd need to actually see your React code, like where/how `InitShowedReviews` is rendered.

Comment: Hi Zeke, Well, in the for loop i call the function to check whether the review is present in the passed array. This aray gets one extra review each time in the for loop. There isn't more code to it. I do not do set state yet. i wil do this after the itteration. because i can't fix this wierd behaviour. I only render the array with initshowedreviews in a later stadium in the code when setted the state. But this part of react I already understand and worked.

Comment: `!ShowedReviews` is always going to be `false` I'm pretty sure.

Comment: but other than that, you shouldn't call `setState` inside the for loop; fully populate `InitShowedReviews` first, then call `setState` after the loop.

Comment: Yeah you’re right about the location of the set state..
But why is it always going to be false in the check? Because when there is something in the array it should become true?

Comment: the array will always be "truthy" even an empty array, so `!array` will always be false.

Comment: Fixed it by the following statement: `if (Array.isArray(ShowedReviews) && ShowedReviews.length)`. But now i'm stuc on the while statement.. Trying to figure that one out.

Comment: Well, it seems to work, with this while loop `while (ShowedReviews.some(e => e.Id === AvailableReviews[ReviewToPass].Id))`. But i get an error of an unsafe variable ReviewToPass? Don't know what that means..